# Difficulty with minimum working example

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, editing-help

I was asked to attach a minimum working example to [Non-OpenMP Fortran code compiled with OpenMP flag behaves differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55960516/non-openmp-fortran-code-compiled-with-openmp-flag-behaves-differently).  However, all subroutines in the code are heavily interconnected in such a way that even if I were able to cut the code as much as reasonably possible, it would not be likely that the error in question is reproduced. This is due to the nature of scientific calculations and convergence criteria used in the code. Is it sometimes reasonable to include big chunks of code in such a case?

Comment: the very intent of an MCVE is to help you isolate the issue. It's VERY possible that, as you do that and isolate the behavior that seems "broken".... you'll  find the exact thing you need to fix to get out of the issue you're finding. If you can't even isolate your issue... how are WE supposed to? :/

Comment: Maybe at the very least show a snippet of what you're talking about. Asking for an MCVE is a standard knee-jerk reaction to seeing a longish difficult question without any code or error at all. But it isn't always possible to provide one. So provide the best you can instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is very unlikely (nearly impossible) to have good answerable questions of this kind without MCVE.

"Debug my code without code" type of question is generally not suitable for SO as the only options are list of random possible reasons of a behavior or post a book-sized answer on debugging which are both too broad.

Posting all code you have is not really an option either as there is generally no value in wall of code for future visitors (as they will not be able to identify problem at hand with code in the post) and question should be closed as "resolved in a way that is not useful for future visitors". Also there is a very good chance that you can't even post code on SO as-is because you can't post it under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license and will have to delete post (or even ask mods to wipe it out).

If you are not willing to work on narrowing down your problem the best option would be to pay someone to solve that issue.

Indeed there rare cases when someone will come and grab all those files and experiment... but you need *very* compelling text to accompany it preferably in some language with enough followers to see how interesting the question is. Your one does not seem to fall in such category.